# CSS Tooltip positioning incorrect and stuck at one place

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to fix a CSS issue, there's and "i" icon image on which the hovering effect is placed. As the mouse moves over it the tool-tip should appear. But the problem is that tool-tip appears but its fixed on one place there are many "i" icons and as we hover on each due to the tool-tip being displayed in one place, hovering on some "i" images is useless as the tool-tip is not visible. These "i" images are placed in  an iframe plus there are many "i" icons so scroll-bar appears so the more bottom of the iframe we reach the tool-tip is not available. Any suggestions and help? Only pure CSS no JS, jquery...says my boss.

The "i" image code:

```
    <div class="sa_statusIn"> Reward Earned
    <span id="sa_status8">
    <img class="sa_status_tooltip" src="i_image_link.png" alt="help" value="help"   width="15" height="15" border="0"><br><a href="v2-importer-facebook-ts.php?tab_provider=3"> Claim Reward </a> <span id="sa_tooltiptxt">Congrats! Another Company system is up &amp; running and we have you to thank. Continue to earn rewards by sharing Company with more of your friends.</span></span>
    <a href="#.php?tab_provider=3"> Claim Reward </a> <span id="sa_tooltiptxt">Congrats! Another Company system is up &amp; running and we have you to thank. Continue to earn rewards by sharing Company with more of your friends.</span></span>
   </div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
.sa_statusIn {
float: left;
width: 29%;
padding: 16px 0 0 24px;
color: #C25A59;
}

img.sa_status_tooltip {
width: 19px;
height: 18px;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
left: 5;
}

img.sa_status_tooltip {
width: 19px;
height: 18px;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
left: 5;
}

#sa_tooltiptxt {
display: none;
background: ffffcc;
margin-left: 145px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 3px 0px 9px 3px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 115px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I still don't get what you want... what exactly is it?

Comment: I guess I was quite ambiguous, excuse me for that. Okay, I have an iframe which loads into another html pages, this iframe has email ids , username..etc and on the right side there is an image/icon with "i" alphabet.Once the user hovers upon the image the tool-tip should appear and it does(somewhat) but as we scroll the iframe down and hover over the "i" image in lower section of the page it does not appear at all because the tool-tip is fixated somewhere meaning it is appearing only in between certain pixels...

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/L33rLdrh/), but there is no tooltip, not even in the wrong position.